# How to sort with condition in JAVA8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Java-8 lambda to sort a list.

Here is list of

```
[(t1, tester1), (t4, tester4), (t3, tester3), (t2, tester2)]
```

after sort

```
[(t2, tester2), (t1, tester1), (t3, tester3), (t4, tester4)]
```

I want to get result as above

```
String specialId = 't2'

List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();

Test test1 = new Test();
test1.setId = "t1"
test1.setName = "tester1"
list.add(test1)

Test test2 = new Test();
test2.setId = "t4"
test2.setName = "tester4"
list.add(test2)

Test test3 = new Test();
test3.setId = "t3"
test3.setName = "tester3"
list.add(test3)

Test test4 = new Test();
test4.setId = "t2"
test4.setName = "tester2"
list.add(test4)

Stream<Test> s1 = list.stream.filter(t -> t.getId.equals(specialId));
Stream<Test> s2 = list.stream.filter(t -> !t.getId.equals(specialId))
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Test::getName));

Stream<Test> s = Stream.concat(s1, s2);

List<Test> result = s.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am getting the expected result. But I want use stream only once.
How can I sort it?

Comment: Is item t2 first, because it is the only exception or is there a more general approach to which items go first?

Comment: In this case, it might be simpler without streams: `List<Test> result = new ArrayList<>(list); result.sort( … );` where you can use the comparator of [kennytm’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42575546/2711488) in the place of `…`.

Answer (score 8):

You could put the special ID treatment into the comparator. The two comparisons can be chained using [thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-).

1. First check if the ID ≠ special ID. Since `false < true`, this will bring the special ID before everything.
2. Then sort by name.

```
Stream<Test> s = list.stream().sorted(
    Comparator.comparing((Test t) -> !t.getId().equals(specialId))
              .thenComparing(Test::getName)
);
```

Comment: There is a small difference to the original code. In the original code, elements having the special id were not sorted (in case there are more than one) in respect to each other. But assuming that ids are unique, this wouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: thanks your code. for example, what if the condition 't1 is last' is added?

Comment: @jakehan If you have more than one special ID, perhaps you should create an `int getIdRank() { return (0 if 't2', 2 if 't1', 1 else) }`, then `Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getIdRank).thenComparing(Test::getName)`. Or even change the ID to a custom class that implements Comparable.

Answer (score 3):

you can do in one sorting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String specialId = "t2";

    List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Test test1 = new Test();
    test1.setId("t1");
    test1.setName("tester1");
    list.add(test1);

    Test test2 = new Test();
    test2.setId("t2");
    test2.setName("tester2");
    list.add(test2);

    Test test3 = new Test();
    test3.setId("t3");
    test3.setName("tester3");
    list.add(test3);

    Test test4 = new Test();
    test4.setId("t4");
    test4.setName("tester4");
    list.add(test4);

    List<Test> sorted = list
            .stream()
            .sorted((t1, t2) -> {
                if (t1.getId().equals(specialId)) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (t2.getId().equals(specialId)) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return t1.getId().compareTo(t2.getId());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    sorted.forEach(System.out::println);
}

static class Test {
    String id;
    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are well aware that streams are lazily evaluated.

```
Stream<Test> s1 = list.stream.filter(t -> t.getId.equals(specialId));
```

You can take out the `Predicate` as you are using the negation in another place.

```
Predicate<Test> specialTestPred = t -> t.getId.equals(specialId);

Stream<Test> specialTestStream = list.stream.filter(specialTestPred);
Stream<Test> nonSpecialTestStream = list.stream.filter(specialTestPred.negate())
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Test::getName));

List<Test> result = Stream.concat(specialTestStream , nonSpecialTestStream)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks for mention it. I will have to figure out predicate.